# Php Regex for currency, no leading zeros unless amount is 0 or 00

Tags: php, regex

Hi im trying to create a regex for currency. The part after the decimal works fine.  However I am having problems with the first part.
I want it to accept numbers such as:

```
00.12
0.12
00
0
```

But not numbers with leading zeros like:

```
0012.12
00023
```

This is what i have but i cannot get it to work

```
^([1-9][0-9]*|0|00)+(\.(\d){2})?$
```

Comment: How is it that `0012.12,` contains leading zeroes but `00.12` and `00` do not?

Comment: So, will we see this question marked as solved? Seems like some thought it was worth the time spent.

Comment: Probably worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Seems like your other question was never resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quantifier `+` on the first capture group -- it will permit multiple repetitions of `0` or `00`.  In other words, `000`, `0000`, `00000`, etc. would be deemed valid as leading portions of the string. The grouping allows for any of the three types. So a regex such as

```
^(0{1,2}|[1-9]\d*)([.]\d\d)?$
```

will achieve your goal.

https://regex101.com/r/Tb1x6x/2/

Comment: I'm curious why you used `[.]` rather than `\.`. Also, why the capture groups? (I see the OP has them but the requirement is not stated.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've run into issues with escaping in the past. Prefer just using a character class.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The groupings are for each pairing. The first is so it can have one or two zeros, or can be an integer 1 or higher (I need to change quantifier actually). The second is so the decimal and two integers can be optional. Could add `?:` to the groupings since the capturing isn't needed. example https://regex101.com/r/Tb1x6x/3/

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check from the front of the string for 1 or more zeros that are followed by a 1 through 9 digit.  This logic means that the required regex pattern can be kept very simple.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ge9OO))

```
$tests = [
    '00.12',
    '0.12',
    '00',
    '0',
    '0012.12',
    '00023',
];
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo $test . (preg_match('~^0+[1-9]~', $test) ? ' fail' : ' pass') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
00.12 pass
0.12 pass
00 pass
0 pass
0012.12 fail
00023 fail
```

To correct your full pattern, you don't need the quantifier on your first group: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EdMmP))

```
echo preg_match('~^(?:[1-9]\d*|0{1,2})(?:\.\d{2})?$~', $test) ? ' pass' : ' fail'
```

But honestly, why not just cast them as floats instead of refusing values with leading zeros?  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l8GQQ))  I would probably do that for a better user experience.  Or maybe just standardize the input numbers with `number_format()`.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R3InZ)) Sounds perhaps like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited]**

Now my answer fits what is really asked:

```
^(0{1,2}|([1-9][0-9]*))(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

You can try this here:
https://regex101.com/r/8KJhk3/5

Comment: Your pattern will permit values to only one decimal place, this is not in the required logic.  The OP also did not declare that they wished to accept `01.23` as a valid value because of the leading zero.  You may ask the OP for clarifications for fringe cases, but stretching the requirements will likely confuse researchers.

Comment: Ok I will edit my answer and adjust it to what the OP asks for, anyway I will leave the other option in case it is the case, I will also ask the OP.

Comment: I find the title to be pretty explicit regarding the expectation with leading zeros.